# How can I add Async Task in my Android Studio project?

Tags: android, mysql, database

I am new to Android and are trying to connect a mysql database to my android app, but I don't get it with the Async Task to work.
What is the best way to use Async Task in here.

Note: "name_db=readSQL1();
System.out.println(name_db+"###########################");" this prints
hier sollte name###########################

Here is my code:

```
 b_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            name_db=readSQL1();
            System.out.println(name_db+"###########################");

            name_to_check=ed_name.getText().toString();
            pw_temp=ed_pw.getText().toString();
            try { pw_hash=hash(getSHA(ed_pw.getText().toString()));
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            for(int i=0;i<user_arr.size();i++) {
                if (name_to_check.equals(user_arr.get(i)) && pw_hash.equals(pw_arr.get(i))) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.example.new_app.UserMain.class).putExtra("user_name",name_to_check));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    tx_counter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tx_counter.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    counter--;
                    tx_counter.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

                    if (counter==0){
                        b_login.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    b_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

}

public static String hash(byte[] hashwert){
    BigInteger number=new BigInteger(1,hashwert);
    StringBuilder hexString=new StringBuilder(number.toString(16));
    while (hexString.length()<32) hexString.insert(0,"0");
    return hexString.toString();
}
public static byte[] getSHA(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
    MessageDigest md=MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    return md.digest(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
public static String readSQL1(){
    Connection conn=null;
    Statement stmt=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    String name="hier sollte name";
    try{
        String url1 = "jdbc:mysql://host.de:3306/h153555_androidstudio?serverTimezone=UTC";
        String user = "username"; String password = "password"; String database="user_db";  //password and username temporary
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, user, password);
        if (conn != null) {
            stmt=conn.createStatement();
            String select="SELECT NAME, PW FROM "+database;
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(select);
            System.out.println("read");
            while(rs.next()){
                name=rs.getString("NAME"); String pw=rs.getString("PW");
            }
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e); System.out.println("read fehler");
    }finally {
        try { rs.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
        try { stmt.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
        try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: firstly, android studio is just an IDE which is helping you to make your app, but your question isn't regarding the IDE at all, it's just asking about a feature _of android_, so there's no need to use the tag :)

Comment: secondly, async tasks are deprecated, you can probably find something better

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in android developers references:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

And you can simply use the FutureTask class
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask

You can use it this way, the Callable call function is the function that run in the task execute process.

```
      FutureTask futureTask_1 = new FutureTask(new Callable<Integer>()
      {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            return 0;
         }
      });
        
      ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
      List<FutureTask> taskList = new ArrayList<FutureTask>();
      taskList.add(futureTask_1);
      executor.execute(futureTask_1);

      futureTask_1.get();
```

Comment: Thank you and one last question, what is the best way to use these with the connection for mysql?

Comment: Its not relevant to your DB connection, you are just need to make sure that you handle the asynchronous code right, even more if you have critical code.
And make sure you open and close the connection in time the receive the data right.